# JMenu generating Menu with different Listener

Tags: java, actionlistener, jmenu

We got the Jmjrst open source project and should configure and work a bit with it.
Now we never had any of the JMenu, JMenuItem and Listener stuff so this is pretty confusing for me.

I already got my new MenuTab implemented and is working.

My problem is that my Task says the following:

> Every plugin should be able to be started and configured.
>
> The configuration should only be implemented if the plugin is configurable.

(translated text)

We got a method for checking if it is configurable.

This is my code right now:

```
    int length = pluginList.size();
    int i = 1;
    for (Plugins plugIn: pluginList) {
        pluginMenuItem = new JMenuItem(plug.getMenuText());
        if (plugIn.isConfigurable()) {
            pluginMenuItem.addActionListener(new MenuListner(m, this));
        }
        if (i < length) {
            pluginsMenu.addSeparator();
        }
        pluginsMenu.add(plugin);
        i++;
    }
```

newList is just a list containing all available plugins. I think my
`if (plug.isConfigurable())` is set incorrectly because every menupoint needs to be able to be clicked. But idk how to manage what is happening when the menu point (plugin) is getting clicked and how to seperate running and configuring.

Edit: every plugin has the following methods: `run()` and `configure()`
but how do I add them to the Menu and am able to seperate them?

Edit2:

```
Plugins ==== The Plugins which should be added to the Menu 
pluginsMenu ==== the JMenu Object
plugIn  ==== the new JMenuButton Object
```

Comment: Your code and variables are confusing. what does collection plugins contains menuItems?  or plugIn object( from foreach loop)? ,.. can you provide actual code snippet ?

Comment: @Sendi_t I edited my question. Please tell me if this clarified it or not.

Comment: If I understand correctly... you have two actions 1.) plugin-configuration   2.) run-plugin ..... are trying to figure out a way to distinguish between the two ? and when to execute which action ?

Comment: well not exactly when to use which but how to being able to select one of the two options (if it is configurable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will depend on your user interface design, you can have **subMenuItems** under each plugin-- one for say "config" and other for "execute/Run",

you can have one menuItem has you have now and then listener can popup the dialog to let user select config/execute -- this will not be the best option as users will have to deal with dialog every time they click the plugin

Another way I can think of is have a top level menuItem for "configuration" and so users clearly can see if they want to configure or change they have to go to "config" menu

SubMenu item is a menuItem itself

```
//a submenu
pluginsMenu.addSeparator();
   submenu = new JMenu("Plugin Name");

      //add one submenuItem
      menuItem = new JMenuItem("Config");
   submenu.add(menuItem);

       //add another submenuItem
       menuItem = new JMenuItem("Run/Execute");
   submenu.add(menuItem);

//add submenu to mainPluginMenu
pluginsMenu.add(submenu);
```

see actual code here [menu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html)

Comment: well can you tell me how I can add subMenuItems? I think I'm gonna go with this because if a plugin is configurable then you can choose whether you want to configure it or run it. if it isn' t configurable then pressing it will run it